# trying to markup safe in flask/jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

how is the proper syntax to markup safe a variable when ever I try to substitute filename is get this when html is parsed

`src="/static/%7B%7B%20car%7Csafe%20%7D%7D"`

I'm using flask to pass in the variable to html
what am i doing wrong whats the proper syntax?
syntax i'm using is

`src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{ car|safe }}')}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily link to a static file in 2 different ways.

**1.** Send the path of your file to your html template with a context:

**In app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

web = Flask(__name__)

@web.route('/')
def example1():
    path_of_file='img/thisismyfile.jpg'
    return render_template('index.html',name_of_file = path_of_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run()
```

**In your html file (for example index.html):**

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename=name_of_file)}}">
```

**2.** Just add your file path in **HTML file**:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/thisismyfile.jpg')}}">
```

Comment: actualy i'm sending list of file names to html and then in html im using for loop to iterate over all the list items
here is the code

```{% for car in carousel %}    
              <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{ car|safe }}')}}" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          {% endfor %}```

Comment: You have a list of file in your static folder and you want to show all of them in your html template with for loop?

Comment: i have stored filenames in database ... fetching filenames from database .. then sending to html and then using for loop to display all the images

Comment: ok ive found my mistake thanks for the hint i just had to remove braces and commas
```"{{url_for('static', filename=car)}}"```

Comment: I was writing a code for you, to get data from database and show them with for loop. anyway, I'm happy to heard that, good luck.